# ListView with 6000 rows c#

Tags: c#, mysql, listview, report

I am with a little issue on handling with one of my applications.
I have a Vessel's historic which is shown on a ListView, but until now I have never needed to show all the data inside this history (the user was using kind of a filter to get what he needed), but now one of the managers want to see all data through the application (they was receiving the full data through an excel report).

The biggest issue is because its 6000 rows with 21 columns each one and when I try to select all the data it takes something between 5 minutes to fully load, but more than that the user need to add new, edit or copy the history, which brings him to a new update on the list with more 5 minutes to load.

I don't quite know how is the best way to handle with this and I wanted your help!

Comment: The first step in addressing a performance problem is to measure and identify the performance problem.  Is the database query taking a long time?  Application logic?  User interface?  "Something is slow, how do I fix it?" isn't an answerable question.  First determine *what* is slow.

Comment: I just want to know some improvements I can do with the ListView with a large amount of rows. What takes more time is the user interface. Would help if I post some of the code?

Comment: What is your UI - WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET? If WinForms - measure the times, like David sugested. I checked my application with ListView, 20 columns 10,000 rows - binding and display time (without loading data from DB) is about 4 seconds.

Comment: I also checked the binding and display time for the DataGridView of the same size (20 columns 10,000 rows) and it is less than a second (about 300ms) - so you may consider using DataGridView which is more suitable for working with many columns and rows. But I guess the data binding is not what is causing the 5-minute delay.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually split the information into sections. Rather than loading 6,000 rows plus columns all at once, why don't you use something like alphabetize the information? Use a different ListView for A-G, then another ListView for H-O, then so on and so forth. That why it would cut down the time it took to query all of the information.

Comment: You say save all the information but just show sections of it, to don't take too long to fully load? Or just have more than one ListView being filled but just showing one each time?

Comment: If you want to save time and still have the ability to see the information, without it taking forever, I would just save all of the information use multiple List Views, but add a button to each of those List Views. So example; If you want to see everything from A-G, press the button for that List View, and only show A-G. All the information will still be saved, but everything won't be displayed all at once.